# How to print results of jq in single row, not pretty formatted

Tags: jq

How can jq get convinced to return results in one row?
Without any options, the results get formatted

```
 echo '{"name":"New release","description":"Super nice release","milestones":["v1.0","v1.0-rc"]}' | jq '.milestones'

[
  "v1.0",
  "v1.0-rc"
]
```

I would like to have it in one row:

```
 echo '{"name":"New release","description":"Super nice release","milestones":["v1.0","v1.0-rc"]}' | jq '.milestones'

["v1.0","v1.0-rc"]
```

Comment: IMO, this is a straightforward reference from the jq manual. The self-answer is not adding anything new to already existing text

Comment: except that google doesnt find anything, when I'm searching for it. Now there's a phrase close to the question out there to be captured.

Comment: google: `jq output on a single line`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the manual

```
    --compact-output / -c:
```

> By default, jq pretty-prints JSON output. Using this option will result in more compact output by instead putting each JSON object on a single line.

can stand in front and behind the filter

```
 echo '{"name":"New release","description":"Super nice release","milestones":["v1.0","v1.0-rc"]}' | jq -c '.milestones'

["v1.0","v1.0-rc"]
```

```
 echo '{"name":"New release","description":"Super nice release","milestones":["v1.0","v1.0-rc"]}' | jq '.milestones' -c 

["v1.0","v1.0-rc"]
```